# Can I make at least one field a requirement on a Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    email = models.EmailField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

For every Person I want to ensure that there is contact information. I don't need both email and telephone (though both is okay) but I need to ensure that *at least one* is provided.

I know I can check this stuff in forms, but is there a way I can do this at Model/database level to save repeating myself?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Write a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method for your model.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def clean(self):
        if not (self.email or self.telephone):
            raise ValidationError("You must specify either email or telephone")
```

If you use a model form (e.g. in the Django admin), Django will call the `clean` method for you. Alteratively, if you are using the ORM directly, you can call the [`full_clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean) method on the instance manually.