# Django model field reference

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have contact model

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    vatkey = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Can i set reference that : when company name is not empty then vatkey is required ?

regards

Comment: Use django validators :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make at least one field a requirement on a Django Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831620/can-i-make-at-least-one-field-a-requirement-on-a-django-model)

Comment: thank all very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django Validatiors.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Contact(models.Model):

     ...
     def clean(self):
         if self.company and not self.vatkey:
            raise ValidationError('Vatkey is required')
```